# ¿Se puede suprimir la leyena con el paquete Performance Analytics?

Tags: r

Estoy usando este código para graficar el pbi de USA y en la parte posterior derecha me sale como leyenda el intervalo de fecha.

```
chart.TimeSeries(A191RL1Q225SBEA, 
                 date.format = "%m-%y", 
                 element.color = "black", 
                 colorset = "red")
```

Quisiera suprimir esa "leyenda" y saber si puedo elegir un rango de fechas distinto. Ej.: los 3 últimos años.

Answer (score 0):

La leyenda del intervalo, lamentablemente, no puede evitarse ya que no es algo configurable por el usuario, al menos sin reescribir el código de la función `plot.xts()` que es la que finalmente se usa para este gráfico. Si quieres explorar esto, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50051183) hay una respuesta al respecto

El otro problema, es como establecer los límites del eje `x`, lo natural sería usar el parámetro `xlim`:

```
chart.TimeSeries(A191RL1Q225SBEA, 
                 date.format = "%m-%y", 
                 element.color = "black", 
                 colorset = "red",
                 xlim = as.POSIXct(c("1970-01-01","2018-12-31"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
)
```

Pero por alguna razón, no está funcionando. Tienes dos alternativas:

#### 1. Guardar el gráfico y usar `set_xlim()` para configurar el rango

```
chart.TimeSeries(A191RL1Q225SBEA, 
                 date.format = "%m-%y", 
                 element.color = "black", 
                 colorset = "red"
) -> p
p$set_xlim(as.POSIXct(c("1970-01-01","2018-12-31"), format="%Y-%m-%d"))
p # Display del gráfico reconfigurado
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2. O filtrar el objeto `xts`

```
chart.TimeSeries(A191RL1Q225SBEA["1970-01-01::2018-12-31"], 
                 date.format = "%m-%y", 
                 element.color = "black", 
                 colorset = "red"
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, mi recomendación es que pruebes pasarte a `ggplot2` sin duda tienes muchas más alternativas de configuración, la única contra (que tampoco es mucha) es que debes pasar tu serie a un `data.frame` para trabajar de forma más cómoda.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(fecha=index(A191RL1Q225SBEA), valor=coredata(A191RL1Q225SBEA))
ggplot(df, aes(x=fecha)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=valor, col="red")) + 
  labs(title="Titulo del gráfico", 
       subtitle="Subtitulo", 
       caption="Fuente", 
       y="Valor", 
       x="Fecha") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]